# How to efficiently mean-pool BERT embeddings while excluding padding?

Tags: pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers

Consider a batch of sentences with different lengths.

When using the BertTokenizer, I apply padding so that all the sequences have the same length and we end up with a nice tensor of shape `(bs, max_seq_len)`.

After applying the BertModel, I get a last hidden state of shape `(bs, max_seq_len, hidden_sz)`.

My goal is to get the mean-pooled sentence embedding for each sentence (resulting in something with shape `(bs, hidden_sz)`), but *excluding* the embeddings for the PAD tokens when taking the mean.

Is there a way to do this efficiently without looping over each sequence in the batch?

Thanks!

Comment: You can refer to https://github.com/Amed1710/Feedback-Prize--English-Language-Learning/blob/main/src/model_zoo/pooling.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pad with `Nan` and then use `torch.nanmean.` You can then change the values back to something less likely to cause gradient issues down the line.

```
mean_pooled = torch.nanmean(hidden_state,dim = 1)
hidden_state = torch.nan_to_num(hidden_state,nan = 0)
```

Alternatively, take the sum of the row and divide by the number of non-zero (assuming 0 padding) elements.

```
mean_pooled = torch.sum(hidden_state,dim = 1) / torch.where(hidden_state != 0, 1,0).sum(dim = 1)
```